Why are bipolar power supplies preferred for use with OLED?
Does anyone know what are the reasons that bipolar power supplies are preferred for use with OLED?

(ELVDD is a positive voltage and ELVSS is a negative voltage)
Image source: https://eureka.patsnap.com/patent-CN104485072A
This is another example from TPS65135.


Where in the patent does it say that ELVSS is a negative voltage?

@MrGerber Sorry I didn't check if the patent said that. Bipolar power supplies are usually used for OLED/AMOLED so I made that notation.

Negative voltages may not be used for passive-matrix OLED displays, for example, those driven by the SSD1306. So we're likely talking about AMOLED displays, and the diagram you show is the two-transistor type.
According to this paper Polysilicon TFT technology for active matrix OLED displays

However, p-channel devices are desired to prevent variations in the
OLED material turn on voltage from leading to current variations in
the OLED material. To accomplish this, a p-type transistor operating
in the saturation mode is used to drive current into the OLED material
because both the gate and source voltages of a p-channel transistor
can be delivered directly via the gate and data lines. However, if an
n-channel TFT were used only the gate voltage could be written
directly to the pixel, the source voltage would depend upon the
voltage across the OLED material.

So using a high-side switch, the voltage required is dependent on the OLED forward voltage. That's typically at least 4V for blue OLEDs, plus you want some voltage across the (rather cruddy TFT) MOSFET - like a few volts- to be in the saturation region. Since that's more than typical 3.3V etc. supply voltages, it makes sense to use a negative rail.
There is materials science work being done on lowering the voltage for OLEDs, which may result in the ability to run from a single rail. It would obviously be desirable to operate from a single Li-ion cell.

You said, "Since that's more than typical 3.3V supply voltages, it makes sense to use a negative rail." Could you explain this further? Also, why not use a low-side switch?

The control voltages are relative to the source of the p-channel TFT transistors, so that supply rail should be the logic Vdd. ELVss must be many volts below that, which works out to be a negative voltage wrt the ground of the logic circuits.
